# Ant writing property file storing filtered properties

Tags: ant, properties

I'm facing a very simple problem with ANT script. I have a script that loads and sets many properties loaded from several property files in file system. This properties are used to preconfigure a new project.

The question is: can I write a new property file persisting all the properties that starts with a given prefix (for example "ref.proj.*")?

The number and the name of the properties is variable and so I cannot use the

```
    <propertyfile file="my.properties">
      <entry  key="ref.proj.first" value="${ref.first}"/>
       ...
      <entry  key="ref.proj.n" value="${ref.n}"/>
    </propertyfile>
```

It's possibile to apply a filter to a propertyfile task?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's taking too long for me to work out all of the kinks. Sorry...

You should look at the [`<echoproperties>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) task. This will let you select the various properties and print them out in *property* = *value* format.

You could use that as your properties file itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot this help me in resolving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the [groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
    <path id="build.path">
        <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-2.1.0.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="create-properties">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy>
            new File("my.properties").withWriter { writer ->
                properties.findAll { it.key.startsWith("ref.proj") }.each {
                    writer.println it
                }
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>
```